# Select target sheet in worksheet_change

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I'm trying to write a vba macro which inserts a Vlookup formula (which should look for a value in another sheet and paste it in **Column C**) in a set of cells when any change is made to the sheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim thisRow As Integer

target.Range = Hoja4.Columns("C")

If target.Column = 1 Then
    thisRow = target.Row
    Range("B" & thisRow).Formula = "=vlookup(B & thisRow,Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,false)"
Else: Exit Do

End Sub
```

Question is, how do I tell the macro that it should run in a specific Sheet?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this code is an event in a specific worksheet, and should be placed inside the sheet you are lokking for the changed events (like modifying the contents of a cell)

Comment: Do you mean how to determine in which sheet the change event should fire (see Shai Rado's answer) or in which sheet it should insert the formula?

Comment: Also, you need to modify your `Vlookup` line from `Range("B" & thisRow).Formula = "=vlookup(B & thisRow,Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,false)"` to `Range("B" & thisRow).Formula = "=vlookup(B" & thisRow & ",Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,false)"`

Answer (score 2):

Like @ShaiRado mentioned, your event code should be running inside a `Worksheet` module. If you want to retrieve a reference to the sheet, or a property (e.g. name) of that sheet then you can use the `Parent` property of the `Target` range. For example in your code it would as follows:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim thisRow As Integer

target.Range = Hoja4.Columns("C")

Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Set wsTarget = Range.Parent
...
```

If you use a `Workbook` level event handler to check for change in *any* worksheet in your `Workbook` then the target sheet is baked into the event signature:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'Sh is the worksheet that has Target i.e the range that was changed
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are many ways to do that.

Below are few ways listed =)

```
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  ' Your Code Goes Here
```

or

```
    Sub test1()
    sheetlist = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")
    For i = LBound(sheetlist) To UBound(sheetlist)
    Worksheets(sheetlist(i)).Activate
    ' Your Code Goes Here
Next
End Sub
```

or

```
        Sub test1() 

            With Worksheets("Sheet1") 
 ' Your Code Goes Here
                End With 


        End Sub
```

I hope this help some :)

Regards

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Looking at changing your code to make it work:

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Was a value in column A changed?
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        'Enter the formula in column C (Offset from column A by 2 columns) of Target sheet.
        'Use R1C1 notation as I find it easier to write in VBA.
        'RC[2] - this Row, Column 2.
        'R1C1:R500C8 - Row 1, Column 1 to Row 500, Column 8 ($A$1:$H$500).
        Target.Offset(, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC2,Personal!R1C1:R500C8,2,FALSE)"
    End If

End Sub
```

If you enter a value in column A it will add the formula to column C.
A value in A4 would give this formula in C4: `=VLOOKUP($B4,Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,FALSE)`

Some pointers on your original code:
`target.Range = Hoja4.Columns("C")` - Target.Range is set as the cell you just entered text into.  I'm pretty sure you can't change it to something else.

`Range("B" & thisRow).Formula` - this will always act on the active sheet as you've not specified a sheet.  Saying that though, as the code is fired from a Worksheet_Change event you can be pretty sure you're on the correct sheet.

`Else: Exit Do` - an `IF...ELSE...END IF` block must always end with an `END IF`.  `Exit Do` is used to exit a `DO...LOOP` and you've not started or ended one in the code so the code would error if it wasn't already looking for an `End If`.

I think your VLOOKUP formula in your original code should be written as:
`"=VLOOKUP(B" & ThisRow & ",Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,FALSE)"`

Your code would paste `=vlookup(B & thisRow,Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,false)` rather than `=VLOOKUP(B1,Personal!$A$1:$H$500,2,FALSE)` (@Shai points this out in their comment).