# Excel Macro to change the background color of the currently selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to practice with VBA.
I wanted to write a Macro that sets the background color of the currently selected cell (to a default option) when I push a button, can anybody help?
Morover, is it possible to set a certain cell to be the activation button for a Macro?
Thanks in advance!
Guglielmo

Answer (score 3):

Use `Selection` to get the currently selected range.

```
Selection.Interior.Color = vbRed 'change color of selection to red
```

---

Or use `Target` of the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` to get the selection whenever it changes.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know something about the second point? using a cell as a button?

Comment: @GuglielmoCervo See [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591885/3219613), but be aware that a cell is not a button and cannot be used as a button. You could insert a hyperlink to click on that launches a macro.

Answer (score 0):

## Worksheet SelectionChange Event

It doesn't work if the cell is already selected. This is not a 'click' event, you could call it a 'select' event i.e. it will get triggered if you select (click on) the cell with the mouse while it wasn't selected or everytime you move to it using the keyboard or even if you use VBA to `Select` or `Activate` it (while it wasn't selected or activated).

### The Code

**Module1**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const cCell As String = "A1"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(cCell)) Is Nothing Then
        Macro
    End If
End Sub
```

**Sheet1**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro()
    MsgBox "You got me started"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please try if the below code might help you to understand the possibilities.
Just by selecting a cell you start "Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange".
By changing a value you start "Sub Worksheet_Change". With the sample code below changed cells are colored in yellow when they are in the defined target range of B1:E20.
Is this what you expect when you say "using a cell as a button"?
YOU HAVE TO ENTER THIS CODE INTO THE WORKSHEET. 
(double click on the worksheet in the VBE editor 
or 
right click on the worksheet name in Excel and select "view code")

```
Option Explicit
Dim oldTarget As Range

Sub SetCellColor()
'
' SetCellColor Macro
' created with macrorecorder
'
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub

'google search for vba color integers
'http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm
Sub see_the_palette_in_Excel()
  Application.CommandBars("Fill Color").Visible = True   ' -- 40 colors
  Application.Dialogs.Item(xlDialogColorPalette).Show
End Sub

'SEARCH ON STACKOVERFLOW FOR worksheet_change target
'
'https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=worksheet_change+target
'e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228431/select-target-sheet-in-worksheet-change

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:E20")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'yellow !
        Application.StatusBar = "Worksheet_Change: " & Target.Address
        Debug.Print "Worksheet_Change: " & Target.Address
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    On Error Resume Next
    If oldTarget.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then
        oldTarget.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.StatusBar = "Worksheet_SelectionChange: " & Target.Address
    Debug.Print "Worksheet_SelectionChange: " & Target.Address
    Set oldTarget = Target
End Sub

Sub SetColor()
Dim ColStr As String
    ColStr = "255, 255, 255"
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(Split(ColStr, ",")(0), Split(ColStr, ",")(1), Split(ColStr, ",")(2)) 'yellow ?
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = ColStr
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub

'vb code for basic colors
'http://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-color-code-list/
'vbBlack
'vbBlue
'vbCyan
'vbGreen
'vbMagenta
'vbWhite
'vbYellow
```